# Problem reinstalling iwlwifi

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

I was trying to reinstall iwlwifi with the command  `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

But when I did that, my terminal told me:

```
Package linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-lowlatency is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-lowlatency' has no installation candidate
```

How can this be fixed? I already have "linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-lowlatency" installed btw.

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?  My Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop offers linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic, but not the lowlatency.

Comment: If it is already installed, as you said, why do you want to reinstall it? May we please see: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.